# C++ RIFF WAVE reader is painfully slow

Tags: c++, audio, wav, binaryfiles

So I've never really worked with binary files before and I'm new to C++. I wanted to read a wav file and output its data section into a txt (seperating the value of each sample with a comma). I also managed to read in the header section, but this code is not important here so I'll not include it.

My wav file stores data in the IEEE 754 standard (floating point numbers) at 32bps. I first read the entire wav file into a char vector and try to work with that afterwards. The output of the program is what I expect it to be, I can play the sound back in Python by reading in the txt without issues. The program is just horribly slow (it takes several minutes for a wav file that is a couple seconds long).

This is `wavReader.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wavFile.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.wav", std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<char> buffer((
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    std::cout << "Loading complete!\n";

    WavFile wavFile = setWavFile(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

This is `wavFile.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct WavFile
{
    uint32_t dataSize;
};

WavFile setWavFile(std::vector<char> buffer);
uint32_t getUint32(std::vector<char> buffer, std::vector<char>::iterator it);
```

This is `wavFile.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WavFile.h"
#include <fstream>

WavFile setWavFile(std::vector<char> buffer) {

    WavFile wavFile;
    std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer.begin();

    // Beginning of data chunk is marked with "data"
    it += 4;
    while (*(it - 4) != 'd' ||
        *(it - 3) != 'a' ||
        *(it - 2) != 't' ||
        *(it - 1) != 'a')
        it++;

    wavFile.dataSize = getUint32(buffer, it), it += 4;
    std::ofstream output("data.txt");

    while (it != buffer.end())
    {
        char outputChar[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; (i++, it++))
            outputChar[i] = *it;
        char* outputStr = outputChar;
        char** outputStrPtr = &outputStr;
        float** outputPtr = reinterpret_cast<float**>(outputStrPtr);
        output << **outputPtr << ", ";
        std::cout << static_cast<double>(std::distance(buffer.begin(), it)) * 100 / wavFile.dataSize << "\%\n";
    }

    return wavFile;
}

uint32_t getUint32(std::vector<char> buffer, std::vector<char>::iterator it)
{
    char outputChar[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; (i++, it++))
        outputChar[i] = *it;
    char* outputStr = outputChar;
    char** outputStrPtr = &outputStr;
    uint32_t** outputPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t**>(outputStrPtr);
    return **outputPtr;
}
```

I made the program print the progress to the console. Note that this only works with wav files that have one channel and store the samples in IEEE 754 standard. You can find the file I used [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nb215rv8rxzv60w/file.wav?dl=0). I'm just a hobby programmer, so forgive me that I have no clue what makes my program this slow... Is it the vector iteration? Or is it the kinda messy variable declarations with reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Actually why don't you read it in python? Converting audio values into text and then back to values seems to be an overkill.

Comment: @VTT This is not for some pratical use, it's rather an exercise I gave myself in order to understand the file structure of a WAVE file and how to convert binary files into human readable files in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the progress printing slows it down? You print a lot. Maybe you can try to print only when the integral value of the percent changes, like:

```
int lastPercent = -1;

loop {
  ...
  float percent = ...;
  int integralPercent = (int)percent;
  if (integralPercent!=lastPercent) {
    lastPercent = integralPercent;
    // print percent here
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh now that's embarassing. I added the progress bar because the program was pretty slow in the beginning and I wanted to know how long it will take. Now I realized that I still used a debug build when I added the progress bar and I used a larger wave file back then. Removing the progress bar entirely and switching to release build solved the issue... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) Just an additional tip: your code around `reinterpret_cast` is not too good. Use `memcpy` instead. If you have a `char *ptr` from your vector, then `float value; memcpy(&value, ptr, 4);` does a better job.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading it completely wrong way. Wave files have RIFF format. Each file consists of RIFF file header and a sequence of chunks.

```
#include <Windows.h> // for DWORD
#include <MMReg.h> // for PCMWAVEFORMATPCMWAVEFORMAT and FORCC

struct t_RiffFileHeader
{
    ::FOURCC m_riff;      // must be 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F'
    ::DWORD  m_file_size; // should be less than or equal to the total file zize
    ::FOURCC m_formtype;  // must be 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E'
};
static_assert(12 == sizeof(t_RiffFileHeader), "");
```

So you first read 12 bytes of this riff header and verify that it is correct.

```
size_t remaining_bytes_count(buffer.size());
const char * p_cursor(buffer.data());
if(remaining_bytes_count <= sizeof(t_RiffFileHeader))
{
    exit(1);
}
const t_RiffFileHeader & riff_header(*reinterpret_cast< const t_RiffFileHeader * >(reinterpret_cast< uintptr_t >(p_cursor)));
if(static_cast< size_t >(riff_header.m_file_size) < sizeof(t_RiffChunkHeader))
{
    exit(1);
}
p_cursor += sizeof(t_RiffFileHeader);
remaining_bytes_count -= sizeof(t_RiffFileHeader);
```

Then you proceed to read chunks.

```
struct t_RiffChunkHeader
{
    ::FOURCC m_id;        
    ::DWORD  m_chunk_content_size;
};
static_assert(8 == sizeof(t_RiffFileHeader), "");
```

You read chunk header and then read `m_chunk_content_size` bytes of data based on chunk id:

- `'f', 'm', 't', ' '` chunk is typically first and should contain  `PCMWAVEFORMAT` structure describing wav data;
- `'d', 'a', 't', 'a'` chunk contains audio data;
- other chunks can be skipped.

If you are done with reading of the last chunk but file end is not reached yet then most likely there is another RIFF file attached. Because of 32-bit length limitation large files are constructed by concatenating several smaller RIFF files.

Comment: I know this. As stated in the question, I managed to read the header information (I also meant that I was able to read the fmt chunk). That's where I got the information from that my sound file has 1 channel, 32bps and stores data in IEEE 754 standard. I simply didn't include this code here because this is not what I worry about. In my example code, I just skipped straight to the data chunk and started reading the data. Now I just want to know why the program is so slow.

Comment: @Keno And this is actually wrong because you can not search for data chunk beginning simply by looking for `data` text as it can appear in custom chunks before the data chunk. As for speed problem, you should not write into `std::cout` after reading each sample. Write report once per 10000 samples or something.

Comment: Thank you, the progress bar was actually the problem. Regarding the data chunk - How would you find out where it starts without looking for "data"? Other chunks are in between the fmt chunk and the data chunk. Let's assume I read in all the info in the fmt chunk and now I want to continue to the data chunk (ignoring the unnecessary stuff in between). How would I do that if there's an aditional "data" written somewhere in between the end of the fmt chunk and the beginning of the data chunk?

Comment: @Keno You read chunks one by one taking chunk size from chunk header.

Comment: Ah okay! So any chunk starts with 4 characters followed by a 32bit chunk size? And I just need to read these two in and skip the size of the chunks I'm not interested in?

Comment: @Keno Yes. Also note that if you managed to read the last chunk but did not reach the end of file there might be another RIFF file following.